# adjustable analog phase shifter

Tags: analog, phase-shift

I am a student.  I am preparing a project to measure 2 sine waves with different phase-shift.  To calibrate my phase-shift measurement device, I need a fair accurate IC / device / product that the generated 2nd phase-shifted can be used to calibrate my measurement device.

Is there any good analog phase shifter IC / device / product that anyone have used before?

Comment: You might have some luck looking into adding a delay line (a specific length of coax cable) to an oscillator for a specific phase shift at a given frequency.

Comment: For low frequencies, the use of AD5933-AD5934 would be ok ...

Comment: For audio frequencies, your PC sound card can generate very accurate phase shifts.

Comment: @kartman is onto the right idea as the dac in the card is likely to be clocked from the same source and then the phases will be locked together. This is likely to be the easiest solution for a student project.  The available frequency will be in the audio range and AC coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f45BF8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

This shows how an XOR logic gate can be used as a phase angle meter. There is a 45 degree phase shift between the two signals, and the XOR output has a duty cycle of 45/180 = 25%. The integrated phase signal is 25% of 5V or 1.25V. This can be scaled and read by a voltmeter in degrees.

Note that I used square waves o 4.5V and 5.5V so they can more easily be identified.

(edit) As for generating two digital signals with precise phase angles, it's probably most easily accomplished with a microcontroller. Generating sine waves might be done with an oscillator and an RC network. You will then need to use a zero crossing detector to get square waves for subsequent angle measurement.

I have designed a precision analog phase shift circuit using two signals at 90 degrees, and then mixing the outputs using a sine/cosine potentiometer. For instance, to get 30 degrees, mix 0.866 of the zero degree signal and 0.5 of the 90 degree signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwH99T.png)</sup>

[image: Mixing two sine waves for 30 degrees]

Note that the resistors were chosen based on 1k/sin(30) and 1k/cos(30)

Comment: How do maintain the phase relationship between the two signal generators? This is easy in spice, but in the real world.... If the frequency of the generators are slightly different (which will happen) the phase will be constantly changing.